# Learn C - How to use gmtime_s

Tags: c

I copied some code from github.
However, I failed to compiled on this method in Visual Studio.
It mentioned that the error is "C4996   'gmtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gmtime_s instead.".
However, I don't quite understand. How could I use "struct tm *buf" in gmtime_s function? From my understanding, the function already return tm type. Why do I need the buf variable as input? Do I expect from "buf" variable?
How could I fix this?

Before

```
struct tm *gmTimer;
gmTimer = gmtime( &timer.time );
```

Should I change to be?

```
struct tm *gmTimer;
struct tm buf;
gmTimer = gmtime_s( &timer.time , &buf);
```

Comment: Those supposedly more secure MS functions are arguably not more secure, because they are easy to mis-use. If you `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before the `#include` statements, you won't get the warning (and be able to write portable code).

Comment: Look at the arguments needed for `gmtime_s` in the online documentation.  What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Here is the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gmtime-s-gmtime32-s-gmtime64-s?view=msvc-160) which has example code.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the supposedly more secure "*MS* functions" are described in [C11, Annex K](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K) (bounds-checking interface).

Comment: @pmg MS's version of `gmtime_s()` isn't the same as in the standard, making it non-standard. The arguments are reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the strange world of C++!
Microsoft has developed set of "more secure" C standard library functions, which are not commonly supported yet. They mainly perform some sort of "out of bounds" checks for arguments. I think at the time you can safely ignore them. Put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before all includes or adding `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` into the Project->Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions.

Comment: Great. With this way, I don't need to modify it.